# Header file undefined reference in c++ while creating a Integer class

Tags: c++, header-files, undefined-reference

I tried creating a Integer class and it looks okay for me but the test program says undefined reference to the overloaded methods. Can someone help me to find out the bug. Any kind of suggestions to fix this bug and improve the code is highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

The following is the error I am getting.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccMork6I.o: in function `main':
testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `MyInteger::MyInteger(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `MyInteger::MyInteger(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, MyInteger const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `MyInteger::getValue() const'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, MyInteger const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `MyInteger::setValue(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `MyInteger::operator+(MyInteger const&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, MyInteger const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `MyInteger::operator-(MyInteger const&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, MyInteger const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x1cc): undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream&, MyInteger&)'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x1df): undefined reference to `MyInteger::operator==(MyInteger const&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `MyInteger::operator==(MyInteger const&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x2b5): undefined reference to `MyInteger::setValue(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x2da): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, MyInteger const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: testMyInteger.cpp:(.text+0x314): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, MyInteger const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the MyInteger.h

```
#ifndef MYINTEGER_H
#define MYINTEGER_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyInteger
{
public:
    MyInteger(int v = 0);
    void setValue(int v);
    int getValue() const;
    MyInteger operator+(const MyInteger &r) const;
    MyInteger operator-(const MyInteger &r) const;
    bool operator==(const MyInteger &r) const;

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const MyInteger &r);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, MyInteger &r);

private:
    int value;
};
#endif
```

Here is the MyInteger.cpp file

```
#include "MyInteger.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// constructer
// initiate the value with v if given else 0
MyInteger::MyInteger(int v = 0){
    value = v;
}

// method to set the value
void MyInteger::setValue(int v){
    value  = v;
}

// method to return the value
int MyInteger::getValue() const {
    return value;
}

// overloading + operator
MyInteger MyInteger::operator+(const MyInteger &r) const {
    MyInteger res;
    res.setValue(res.getValue() + r.getValue());
    return res;
}

// overloading - operator
MyInteger MyInteger::operator-(const MyInteger &r) const {
    MyInteger res;
    res.setValue(res.getValue() - r.getValue());
    return res;
}

// overloading comparison operator (==)
bool MyInteger::operator==(const MyInteger &r) const {
    MyInteger res;
    return res.getValue() == r.getValue();
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const MyInteger &r){
    out << r.getValue();
    return out;
}

istream &operator>>(istream &in, MyInteger &r){
    int tmp;
    in >> tmp;
    r.setValue(tmp);
    return in;
}
```

The following is my driver code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyInteger.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MyInteger i1;       // 0
    MyInteger i2(5);    // 5
    MyInteger i3 = i2;  // 5

    cout << "i1: " << i1 << endl;
    cout << "i2: " << i2.getValue() << endl;
    cout << "i3: " << i3 << endl;

    i1.setValue(-4);
    i3 = i1 + i2;
    cout << "i3: " << i3 << endl;              // 1

    cout << "i2 - i1: " << i2 - i1 << endl;    // 9

    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin >> i1;                                 // enter 123

    if (i1 == i2)                              // different
        cout << "same" << endl;
    else
        cout << "different" << endl;

    i2 = i1;
    if (i1 == i2)                              // same
        cout << "same" << endl;
    else
        cout << "different" << endl;

    i2.setValue(25);
    cout << "i1: " << i1 << endl;              // 123
    cout << "i2: " << i2 << endl;              // 25

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `but the test program says undefined reference to the overloaded methods.` Please add the _full_ error message.

Comment: Please provide the full error message.

Comment: @Michael that is in the MyInteger.cpp file

Comment: It is also helpful to include the call to the compiler, but I think I could reverse engineer it.

Comment: @Jacobe how do you compile?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please only use related tags. C and C++ are very different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the code doesn't compile due to the definition of the constructor of `MyInteger`. The default argument `= 0` is given in both declaration and definition, which is invalid. Just remove it in the implementation, and you should be fine:

```
MyInteger::MyInteger(int v){
    value = v;
}
```

Second, you need to link everything together after incrementally build object files from `.cpp` files. Example:

```
g++ -o MyInteger.o -c MyInteger.cpp
g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp

g++ -o test-exec main.o MyInteger.o
```

Comment: Sure, just post a new question as this are separate concerns.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you compiled only with the `main.cpp`-file and not the `MyInteger.cpp`-file. I.e. your call to the compiler was something like:
`g++ main.cpp`

And it should be like
`g++ main.cpp MyInteger.cpp`